# Won't install with valid c installation

Tags: tensorflow, go

I am trying to install tensorflow for Go I installed it for c and tested it without an error but now that I tried the instructions on the tensorflow website

> go get github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go
> go test github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go

I get a lot of errors
what I think could be the root of the problem is there are headings in the error messages, because the error messages have hashtags in them I don't know how important they are so I left them in there. thanks a lot for your help.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 851 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 1959 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 2329 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 2517 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 2732 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 2733 (>= sh_info of 2)
# github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go.test
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 851 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 1959 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 2329 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 2517 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 2732 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 2733 (>= sh_info of 2)
```

but I do not know how I could fix it and what is wrong
here is the full error message

```
# github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 851 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 1959 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 2329 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 2517 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 2732 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 2733 (>= sh_info of 2)
# github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go.test
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 851 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 1959 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 2329 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 2517 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 2732 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../libtensorflow.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 2733 (>= sh_info of 2)
--- FAIL: TestOperationAttrs (0.02s)
attrs_test.go:173: bad value for attribute "value": Malformed TF_STRING tensor; element 0 out of range (memory will be leaked)
2021-01-08 01:48:39.679148: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-01-08 01:48:39.701046: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:104] CPU Frequency: 2095900000 Hz
2021-01-08 01:48:39.701480: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x37b6b00 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2021-01-08 01:48:39.701505: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2021-01-08 01:48:39.742984: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:31] Reading SavedModel from: ../cc/saved_model/testdata/half_plus_two/00000123
2021-01-08 01:48:39.744365: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:54] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
2021-01-08 01:48:39.744411: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:250] Reading SavedModel debug info (if present) from: ../cc/saved_model/testdata/half_plus_two/00000123
2021-01-08 01:48:39.746044: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:215] Restoring SavedModel bundle.
2021-01-08 01:48:39.754014: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:199] Running initialization op on SavedModel bundle at path: ../cc/saved_model/testdata/half_plus_two/00000123
2021-01-08 01:48:39.758081: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:319] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success: OK. Took 15137 microseconds.
--- FAIL: TestSessionWithStringTensors (0.00s)
panic: nil-Operation. If the Output was created with a Scope object, see Scope.Err() for details. [recovered]
    panic: nil-Operation. If the Output was created with a Scope object, see Scope.Err() for details.

goroutine 67 [running]:
testing.tRunner.func1.1(0x8a1920, 0xa1c040)
    /usr/lib/golang/src/testing/testing.go:999 +0x319
testing.tRunner.func1(0xc00022a120)
    /usr/lib/golang/src/testing/testing.go:1002 +0x402
panic(0x8a1920, 0xa1c040)
    /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/panic.go:969 +0x166
github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go.Output.c(...)
    /home/username/go/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/operation.go:130
github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go.(*Graph).AddOperation.func4(0x3c427f0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/username/go/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/graph.go:324 +0xe9
github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go.(*Graph).AddOperation(0xc000127440, 0x98941c, 0x16, 0x98941c, 0x16, 0xc000157d00, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc000157d60, 0x0, ...)
        /home/username/go/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/graph.go:324 +0x68b
github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go.TestSessionWithStringTensors(0xc00022a120)
    /home/username/go/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/session_test.go:246 +0x25e
testing.tRunner(0xc00022a120, 0x99ff50)
    /usr/lib/golang/src/testing/testing.go:1050 +0xdc
created by testing.(*T).Run
    /usr/lib/golang/src/testing/testing.go:1095 +0x28b
FAIL    github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go  0.329s
FAIL
```

Comment: Try to follow instruction at `readme.md` of the https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/go. Its quite different and more detailed. `go get ...` way too few steps to install tensorflow.

Comment: the error stays the same for the most part it starts later at # github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go.test. but while installing I followed all the steps but after using bazel to compile tensorflow I only got the libtensorflow.so file but not the libtensorflow_framework.so file additionally my file explorer tells me that my bazel-bin link is broken but it was able to copy libtensorflow.so out of it